# php переход в случайную папку

Tags: php

Как к примеру перейти в случайную папку а затем сохранить этот путь? Начальная точка корень сайта)

Comment: не по теме сами то пытались сделать

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$path="/";
$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);
$files = array();
foreach ($iterator as $info) {
  if (is_dir($info->getPathname())) {
    $dirs[] = $info->getPathname();
  }
}
chdir($dirs[rand(0, count($dirs)-1)]);
?>
```

PS конкретно этот код не тестировал, так что могут быть досадные мелочи

Comment: @Naumov, будет полезнее, если вы явно укажите на ошибку.

Comment: @Nofate Ошибка довольно интересная, на виду,  но сложно повторить, если проэкт более менее крупный. то сложно будет отловить... А если указать то человек забудет об этом и допустит её... А не указать другой скопипастит и вставит... Делема. Ok. смотрим на строку `chdir($dirs[rand(0, count($dirs))]);`, `если rand()` вернёт максимальное число `count($dirs)` последний аргумент то `notice undefined index`  а `chdir` выдаст `warning` т.к. в его аргумент будет передан `null` так и упадёт скрипт. А так как у многих отключены `notice` и `warning` то безполезно искать проблему.

Comment: `undefined index` так как ключи в масиве с 0 начинаються а `count` сщитает от 1 т.е. массив `0,1,2,3` будет иметь 4-элемента, а заканчиваться индексом 3. Пофиксить просто `rand(0,count($dirs)-1)` @Nofate

Comment: @Naumov, исправлено.